# Avoid alert when making call from uiwebview inside app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, call, uialertview

The Scenario is that I need to make a call from my app and get control back to app when the call ends without any input from the user. But the following code does not allow to make call without responding to the alert. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phoneno]];
    UIWebView *mCallWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]  ;
    [self.view addSubview:mCallWebview];
    [mCallWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but for security reasons is **NOT** possible!
Allowing to make a call directly without asking user may open the door to unwanted call to high-toll services... or even worst frauds...

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a webview. Just tried this and it works, plus it's more straightforward

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phoneno]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL];
```

Comment: The original poster requires that the control returns to the app. Using tel URL scheme won't help.